# use getJSON with variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I apologize beforehand if the question is not clear, but i'll try.

I currently have this code that pull the status of all the devices from my home automation controller.

```
function pull_light_status (lights_array) {
        $.getJSON( "resources/php/getjson.php", function( json ) {
            var vera_obj = json;
            $.each(lights_array,function(myindex, myvalue){
            var id_del_object = myvalue;
            var id_status = vera_obj.devices[id_del_object].states[0].value;
        })
        })     
    }
```

Due to the structure of the object i get its getting really hard for me to work with that object so I'm thinking in using another route.

I can get the status of an specific device by using this php called change_state.php

```
<?php
$url = 'http://ip:port/data_request?id=variableget&DeviceNum' . $_POST['device_id'] . "&serviceId=urn:upnp-org:serviceId:SwitchPower1&Variable=Status";
$jsondata_send = file_get_contents($url);
//echo $jsondata_send;
?>
```

My question is:
Is it possible to replace the JS to something that will allow me to request the json response of a device variable I specify?

Something like this?

```
function pull_light_status (lights_array) {
        $.each(lights_array,function(myindex, myvalue){
            $.getJSON( "resources/php/change_state.php",{ device_id: + myvalue})
                      .done(function(json) {
                var vera_obj = json;
                console.log (vera_obj);
            })
        })
    }
```

What I would expect in return is a 0 or 1, that way I can play with the status of the devices.

Comment: Something *like* that should work, although your PHP is looking for a `$_POST` variable; by definition, any `data` parameters passed via `getJSON()` will be in `$_GET` (and `$_REQUEST`).

Comment: in change_state.php you should read `$_GET['device_id]` variable if you are using GET request. However if you update some data in server, you should use POST instead of GET

Comment: Thanks for the tip, i tried both but none worked, i dont get anything on the console. On the network i see this when i inspect 10.0.0.119/resources/php/change_state.php?device_id=12 but on the console i dont get anything in return

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `$.post` since you are expecting a `POST` payload on the `php` side.

```
function pull_light_status (lights_array) {
    $.each(lights_array,function(myindex, myvalue){
        $.post( "resources/php/change_state.php", { device_id: myvalue })
            .done(function( data ) {
                var vera_obj = json;
                console.log (vera_obj);
        });
    })
}
```

While on the `php` side you need to make sure that you are sending back a `json` encoded string.
So a `var_dump($jsondata_send);` would be in order, if it's all right, print it out along with the headers.

```
<?php
    $url = 'http://ip:port/data_request?id=variableget&DeviceNum' . $_POST['device_id'] . "&serviceId=urn:upnp-org:serviceId:SwitchPower1&Variable=Status";
    $jsondata_send = file_get_contents($url);

    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    print $jsondata_send;
?>
```

If you want to use `getJSON` instead, in the php file, change `$_POST['device_id']` into `$_GET['device_id']`

Comment: Thanks i tried your recommendations i just had to do a slight change on line var vera_obj = json;  i changed to var vera_obj = data;  and it seems to be working. THANKS A TON!!!!!!